# Suma de una secuencia utilizando recursividad

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursión

La idea del código es tomar una función con los siguientes parámetros: `start`, `stop`, `step`. `start` indica el primer número, `stop` el último y `step` la diferencia entre cada número y la idea es sumar los elementos de la secuencia.

Por ejemplo, en el caso de los siguientes parámetros: (2,5,2) la secuencia sería 2,4 y el resultado sería 6. Este es el código que se me ocurrió pero no funciona correctamente:

```
def recursive(start,stop,step):
    if start>=stop:
       return start
    else:
       return start+recursive(start+step,stop,step)
```

El código funciona bien cuando `start` iguala el valor de `stop` como en el caso de los parámetros (2,6,2) pero en el caso de (2,5,2) la salida es 2+4+6 y la idea es que solamente sume 2+4.

Answer (score 1):

La causa está en el condicional, imaginemos el caso que comentas, la secuencia de llamadas sería:

- `recursive(2, 5, 2)`, 2 > 5, luego se retorna `2 + recursive(2+2, 5, 2)`.
- `recursive(4, 5, 2)`, 4 > 5, luego se retorna  `4 + recursive(4+2, 5, 2)`
- `recursive(6, 5, 2)`, 6 <= 5, luego retorna 6.

Ahora hay que entender como funciona la recursividad que básicamente se comporta como una pila, la primera llamada a la función es la última en retornar y es de la que obtienes el resultado. Cuando se produce la primera llamada a la función esta retorna `2 + recursive(2+2, 5, 2)` pero no puede retornar hasta que `recursive(2+2, 5, 2)` se complete y le retorne algo que sumar a 2, lo mismo pasa con las siguientes llamadas, de forma que la última llamada es la primera en completarse y retornar algo y a partir de ahí sigue la cadena hacia atrás hasta llegar a la primera llamada.

Es decir, cuando la tercera llamada `recursive(6, 5, 2)` retorna `start` (6), la segunda puede continuar y retorna `4 + 6)`, cuando esto se produce la primera llamada puede retornar y nos retorna `2 + 10` por lo que obtenemos 12.

El problema es que la tercera llamada nunca debió producirse, porque 6 es mayor que 5. Una posible solución siguiendo tu idea original  es modificar el condicional y en vez de comparar `start` comparar `start + step`, por ejemplo:

```
def recursive(start,stop,step):
    sum_ = start + step
    if sum_ > stop:
        return start
    return start + recursive(sum_, stop, step)
```

> ```
> >>> recursive(2, 5, 2)
> 6
> >>> recursive(2, 6, 2)
> 12
> ```

De lo anterior se deriva uno de los problemas de la recursión, cada llamada recursiva implica la creación de un nuevo frame en la pila de llamadas  y la pila no es infinita, esto puede terminar causando un desbordamiento de la misma (Stack Overflow...). Tener en cuenta que Python no realiza una optimización de la recursión de cola (que no es tu caso de todas formas) como también ocurre en otros lenguajes (aunque en el caso de Python es más bien porque Guido van Rossum no aprecia la recursión demasiado...) por lo que si la función fuera recursiva de cola aún tendríamos el mismo problema.

Por defecto Python limita las llamadas recursivas a 1000 para proteger la pila de C (su desbordamiento significa el final de malas formas del intérprete y eso no es bueno...), es un límite bastante conservador y podemos elevarlo algo con cuidado mediante [`sys.setrecursionlimit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit) aunque generalmente en estos casos optar por otras aproximaciones (iteración, memoization, etc) es mejor idea.